# Optionsmenu in an TabActivity for a specific Tab

Tags: android, menu, tabactivity

My problem is, that I have got a TabActivity, which has 4 Tabs right now. The first Tab is a special Details-Tab, where the user could modify some data.

The problem is, that if I add a OptionsMenu for the Activity, that the OptionsMenu is appearing on every Tab.
I tried to check the current **mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()** in the **onCreateOptionsMenu** but that changed nothing.
So, how to do that?

(The following code, which still shows the OptionsMenu on every Tab)

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
  if(mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()==getString(R.string.tab_details)) {
   boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   menu.add(0, EDIT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_edit).setIcon(R.drawable.edit);
   return result;
  }    

  return true;
 }

 public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case EDIT_ID: {   
        Toast.makeText(this, "o.O", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
       }
  }

  return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
 }
```

Comment: Have you created an activity for each Tab?

Comment: No, its one activity, which has got a TabHost with 4 tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are comparing strings (tags in fact) with ==, usually, this is nicer to do that with `.equals()` method. Maybe it will solve your issue.
To dynamically update an option menu (from the documentation) :

> If you want to change the Options
>   Menu each time it opens, you must
>   override the onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Comment: Well, its nicer, but doesn't solve the problem. Because it rans into that IF all the time.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure you can get an optionMenu which would be different on each tab, because, it is Activity specific. As you are staying in the same activity within your 4 tabs, the menu is the same. So you might want to use a context menu.

Comment: Sorry didn't read the documentation properly. If you want to change the optionmenu everytime you open it, you need to use onPrepareOptionMenu and do the changes in it.